# insert PHP code in mysql from POST?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `textarea` form and I send this to PHP `POST`.

php receive the POST and insert in mysql:

```
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (descricao) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $descricao);
$stmt->execute();
```

It is inserting fine. The problem is if I try to add PHP code in my textarea, like:

```
text...
<?php
echo"";
?>
text...
```

`descricao` will only have this:

```
text...



text...
```

how can I add the php code in mysql? why it is not working?

Comment: Is the php code inserted into database? I mean whether your problem is that it is not displayed when given in a textarea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this using PDO:

```
    $descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO post(descricao) VALUES(:des_value)";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(
           ':des_value' => $descricao,
    ));
```